# how to rank the column in pyspark with group by clause

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
 A     B    C   
---------------
A1    B1   C1
A1    B1   C2
A1    B1   C3

A2    B1   C1
A2    B1   C2
A2    B1   C3

A3    B2   C1
A3    B2   C2
A3    B2   C3
```

How do I  rank as per column A,B? Expected Output:

```
 A     B    C   rank
-----------------------
A1    B1   C1    1
A1    B1   C2    2
A1    B1   C3    3

A2    B1   C1    1
A2    B1   C2    2
A2    B1   C3    3

A3    B2   C1    1
A3    B2   C2    2
A3    B2   C3    3
```

I want to perform group by on column A,B and give the rank as per change in value of column C..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
df.withColumn("rank", F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy("A", "B").orderBy("C")))
```